# Import ova file using mac terminal onto Vmware Fusion

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

This is the first question I am posting and I will be try to as thorough and exact as possible.

I have a my_vm.ova file and VMware Fusion on my mac. I can import the ova file through the GUI of VMWare fusion.

But I want to import my_vm.ova file using the mac terminal into VMwareFusion.

I have searched a lot online and came across few articles but of no help. All articles were about VirtualBox.

Please let me know if there is a command for mac terminal which imports .ova file to VMWare Fusion
I got this by digging but doesnt work for me or maybe I am using it wrong:

`ovftool https://my_ovf_server/ovfs/my_vapp.ova /vm/my_vm.vmx
   (.ova file to .vmx file)`

The above command gives the following error:

`Error: OVF Package is not supported by target:
 - Line 25: Unsupported hardware family 'vmx-12'.
Completed with errors`

I have VMWareFusion 8.0 and the ovftools it came with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here 
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/468121?start=0&tstart=0

The steps are:

1. Change hardware family to vmx-10(10 in mycase) on .ovf file
2. Match the checksum in .ovf and .mf file(on mac youcan find checksum using `shasum`)
3. run the ovf to vmx command(`ovftool <path_to_ovf_file> <path_to_target_folder>`)
4. run the vmrun command(`vmrun --powerOn <path_to_file>`) to start vm